# MacBook Pro 2019 keeps restarting when boot into macOS or macOS standalone installer via USB

Tags: macbook-pro

I have disabled Secure Boot and removed Activation Lock on my MacBook Pro 2019 to be able to install Ubuntu to my MacBook.
After a time using Ubuntu, now I want to reinstall MacOS but I can not.
I have tried to create a USB with both Mac Ventura and Monterey installer (that my MacBook previously supported and worked well)
I have tried to:

- Startup from Mac Recovery option using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, My MacBook restart once, indicates that it is downloading recovery from Internet twice then got failed with error -1008F, in both startup ways.
- Started the macOS installer from USB, and tried both Ventura and Monterey, but my MacBook keeps restarting.
- Reset NVRAM and SMC

But they do not help at all.

I guess it failed because I deleted the internal SSD NVME partition table APFS, then reinstall it with the Linux partition table.

I tried to boot into Ubuntu from USB, to re-create the GPT partition table for the internal SSD.
But it does not help, either.

I tried to create an external SSD with an APFS partition and then clone it to an internal SSD using Clonezilla but Clonezilla can not create a partition table on an internal SSD.

Comment: -1108F is a connectivity error. How, specifically, did you make the USBs? As far as I'm aware, Ubuntu doesn't understand APFS.

Comment: You must have used a different Mac to create the USB installers. Have you tested to see if the installers will boot on the Mac used to create them? Ubuntu includes `gdisk` which is capable of creating APFS partitions. Creating the partition is not the same as formatting to create a APFS container inside the APFS partition.

Comment: @Tetsujin The error code is 1008F, not 1108F.
I used other Macs to make the USBs. However, all Macs I used to make USBs are M1 Mac. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Yes. I have used other Macs to make the USBs. I have a MacMini 2020 and a MacBook Pro 14 inch 2021. Both of them are Apple Silicon (M1 and M1 Pro).

Comment: And also, the USBs I created work well with my other Mac, except the Pro 2019 version one

Comment: Can you get one of the other Macs to boot from Internet Recovery? If not, then you might want to try again later.

Comment: Sorry, typo, 1008F. [I'm working on a laptop for the first time in 35 years of using Macs & every single button & feature seems to be in the wrong place ;))

Comment: Thank you all. I have found out that my Macbook firmware was corrupted. So I used another Mac to restore it's firmware. My Mac is now working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have fixed my Macbook thank to this post: [Macbook Air 2019 will not boot from USB or complete Internet Recovery, Exhausted options](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402265/macbook-air-2019-will-not-boot-from-usb-or-complete-internet-recovery-exhausted?rq=1)

My Mac's firmware was corrupted. I used another Mac to reset it in DFU mode.

Read more at Apple's Documentation:
https://support.apple.com/en-vn/guide/apple-configurator-mac/apdd5f3c75ad/mac

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).